# Hibernate delete and insert in one transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, transactions

Here is my JPA repository:

```
interface ClientApplicationPriorityRepository : JpaRepository<ClientApplicationPriority, Long> {

    fun deleteAllByClientId(clientId: String): Int
}
```

Here is my method where I need first to delete and second to insert (the priority is important):

```
@Transactional
    public void saveClientApplicationPriorities(String clientId, Boolean isFoldersPresented, List<ClientApplicationPriority> clientApplicationPriorities) {
        clientApplicationPriorityRepo.deleteAllByClientId(clientId);
        clientApplicationPriorityRepo.flush();
        if (isFoldersPresented) {
            clientApplicationPriorityRepo.saveAll(clientApplicationPriorities);
        }
    }
```

I have to do it in a transaction, but after the method in tests I see that nothing was deleted from the DB. What's the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to annotate your deleteAllByClientId() function with the followings:

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
```

Comment: I thought so, but it didn't help

Comment: note that `@Transactional` internally works by creating a proxy, so you must call that public method from another component, otherwise you'll bypass the proxy and the transaction won't be created. How are you calling `saveClientApplicationPriorities`?

Comment: Exactly what  @user2340612  is saying. This concept is known as self-invocation and is not supported in Spring AOP.